# Rendering two views at the same time, or a partial and a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a site right now where I have a standard layout, with a view/template.  I've spent the past 2 weeks trying to get ajax functionality working, but it's not working and I need an alternative.  Is it possible to render a partial WITHIN a view?

As in, layout (view (partial))    sort of thing?

Right now I just have a standard layout and view with a yeild in the layout.  There is an empty div in the view where the ajax HTML was supposed to go, I want to fill it with a partial for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes surely, you can call a partial inside any view file. For example, you have a view file 'index.html.erb' and you want to call a partial '_new_partial.html.erb'

In your view file.

```
<div>
  <%= render :partial => 'new_partial' %>  #provide complete path if partial is not in the same directory.
</div>
```

Comment: excellent.  One more question that I just thought of now:  is it possible to hit a controller for it too?  Just to pull some data from the models

Comment: You can hit a controller by clicking on some link or via some form request.